# Why does Angular's renderer.listen() de-select the text?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, renderer

(Context: I am making an email processor which shows an email on a web page)

I use Angular's Renderer2 for listening to clicks in a certain area. I do this because I have generated some content with innerHTML and (click) can not be applied to innerHTML.

The clicks get catched fine but when I try to select text inside this area, the text gets de-selected when I release my mousebutton, this is because of the renderer.listen().

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

```
@ViewChild('listener') listener;
...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.listener.nativeElement, 'click', (evt) => {
      if (evt.path[0].id.includes('plus')) {
        this.lightboxService.showBox(evt.path[0].src);
      }
    });
  }
```

Edit: The problem is not caused by the `showBox()` method, it is solely caused by the renderer. When I am using the renderer without any methods, the problem still occurs. The listener fires on clicks, this means clicks on text as well.

I cannot prevent this by limiting the listening area to only the images since I do not know where the images will be placed.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your problem but you are aware that selecting text is also a "click", just some sort of "delayed click"? A "click" in JS is, if i'm not mistaken, pressing mousebutton down and then, after some time, releasing the mousebutton again.

Comment: Can you explain what does the `this.lightboxService.showBox(evt.path[0].src);` line do? I suspect that it changes state in such a way that the component with the text needs to be rerendered (which results in de-selecting of the text)

Comment: Please add the source code for `showBox()`.

Comment: Thank you all for responding 
@LambdaCruiser the `showBox()` method is not the cause for the error, the cause is solely the renderer. When I delete the if statement (including the `showBox()` method) the problem still occurs. So even with an empty renderer the problem continues.

Comment: @cgTag Please read my previous comment, showBox does not cause the problem so I don't think it would be benificial to post the code.

Comment: @spyro yes, that is correct. This is causing the issue but my question is, how can I solve this? As far as I know, I can't pick another event type except for "click".

I use it to listen for clicks on innerHTML images, but it may ignore the text. It is not ignoring the text now, the click event fires and the text gets de-selected.

Minimizing the listening area to only the images is not an option since I do not know where the images will be placed, I am making an email processor for a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For acting different on certain "click" types on the same area, you need to use "mouseDown" and "mouseUp" instead of just "click".

When you are using "mouseDown", the event fires when the mousebutton is pressed down and the event gives you the coordinates of the event. "mouseUp" fires when you release the button and this also gives you the coordinates of the event.

You now have coordinates, for example 5/5, from the first event and 5/30 from the 2nd event. This means that the user has moved the cursor 25 pixels in one direction. This would not be consideres a "click" in your terms because the cursor moved 25 pixels.

If coordinates from both events are the same, like 5/5 and 5/5, then you can consider this a "click" and do execute further code.

You can adjust this and let a combination of 5/5 to 6/6 also pass as "clicked" because the user only moved 1 pixel in each direction and mostly didnt wanted to mark something.

I hope this helps you. If you have furzer questions, just comment under this answer :)

Comment: I didn't know there are several 'click' events, changing 'click' to 'mousedown' worked for me, thanks! But I had to change 'mouseDown' to 'mousedown', it didn't work with the upper case d.

Comment: @MikeGomper Glad i could help :) The writing of "mousedown" and "mouseup" differs depending on the framework and language. in plain JS those events can have different writing as in angularJS, Angular and other languages like c# but all of those do have some "mousedown" and "-up" events which you can then google for in a specific case :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes that would be correct, I am using Angular 6.